# Colors in timestamps on Meta Stack Exchange do not indicate "recentness"

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, meta, timestamps

I am used to see timestamp everywhere by it's color. The recent timestamps are a little bit reddish everywhere. E.g. in Meta Stack Overflow:

**Last edit:**

> [image: Last edited on MSO]

**Last seen:**

> [image: Last seen on MSO]

But in Meta Stack Exchange they have same color everywhere even for recent time:

**Last edit:**

> [image: Last edited on MSE]

**Last seen:**

> [image: Last seen on MSE]

Please make it something like this:

> [image: Expected color in MSE]

Comment: Recentness is an actual word by the way. :D

Comment: I actually like it this way. It doesn't stand out so it doesn't bug me. The last thing we need is bloating the interface with unecessary details that stand out more than they should.